# RequestFactory javax.validation.ValidationException NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gwt, guice, requestfactory

I use Guice along with GWT 2.4 but I get a `javax.validation.ValidationException NoClassDefFoundError` when I run the server. In the `pom.xml` file I referenced the correct dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but in Eclipse I can't see the `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` in the `Maven Dependencies` tree. The behavior is pretty strange:

- I can find `validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar` and `javax.validation-validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar` under the `target` directory. I don't understand why it's there.
- In the `Maven Dependencies` tree of eclipse, I can see a reference to `javax.validation-validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar` which contains 5 packages but no classes.

Running the app outside eclipse works. I run it using `mvn gwt:run`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the dependency `gwt-user`, I managed to fix it by excluding the dependency on `validation-api`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```